# Does CN4 with the following structure exist?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, identification, carbon-family, pnictogen

I am a mathematician, not a chemist, so my questions are rather combinatorial. I am intrigued by the possibility of the following binary compound:

$$\ce{\overset{-}{N}=\overset{+}{N}=C=\overset{+}{N}=\overset{-}{N}}$$

which ought to be isoelectronic with carbon suboxide, and thus possibly stable. Does this compound exist, even in interstellar space?

Comment: Now that's an interesting question. After all, [diazomethane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diazomethane) **is** a thing.

Comment: There were 0 hits on [ChemSpider Structure Search](http://www.chemspider.com/Search.aspx?rid=d501209a-b09c-44aa-982c-1aa8466f53d0).

Comment: Looks horrendously unstable

Comment: [Cyanogen azide](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja01074a071), $\ce{(N$\!\equiv\!$C-N=N^+=N^-)}$, is pretty similar but not quite.

Comment: Does not sound like something anyone would want to handle http://blogs.sciencemag.org/pipeline/archives/2008/07/14/things_i_wont_work_with_cyanogen_azide

Comment: Diazidomethane is a thing too - though not a thing you want to make. Org. Process Res. Dev.  (2008) 12 1285

Comment: I suspect it is going to be hard to make this substance, no mention in Reaxys. I think it might be an impossible compound to make. If you do make it take care work using a long pair of tongs to handle it, a kevlar jacket, heavy gloves, good eye protection and ear defenders.

Comment: @Oscar Lanzi maybe on top of the ear defenders, face shield and arc flash glasses (UV blocking) one should wear the Ned Kelly helmet (Steel bucket with a small eye slot), maybe one should work from behind a sheet of thick steel using a master slave manipulator or maybe choose a different synthetic target to work on.

Comment: I was hoping that you chaps, knowing more about this than I, could supply illuminating observations about the stability of the molecule, and the parallels with carbon suboxide.  I can get banter about protective lab gear without going to the lengths of signing up to chemistry stack-exchange.  Come on - what are you made of?

Comment: @ThomasForster as far as I can tell, this compound has never been synthesized, so it is difficult to say for certain whether it would be stable. However, based on the the existence of similar compounds (diazomethane, cyanogenazide) that are at least thermodynamically stable, the simplicity of compound, and the caveat of accepting interstellar space, where the compound is likely to be kinetically stable due to the low temperature, I would say it is likely it does exist. For further supporting evidence, QM calculations could be done to confirm its thermodynamic stability.

Comment: @ThomasForster Confirmation that this compound isn't known experimentally: https://books.google.com/books?id=FA7VAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT178&lpg=PT178&dq=carbon+suboxide+isoelectronic&source=bl&ots=XBXyf1RRqV&sig=2z1T5kuGniPUtUZTfKlYBZGP7bU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjZmKTItJfbAhUJSa0KHTkXBasQ6AEIcTAJ#v=onepage&q=carbon%20suboxide%20isoelectronic&f=false From what I have found about similar compounds, it is likely that your compound is bent into a V shape, similar to [pentazenium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentazenium)

Comment: Carbon suboxide has a very shallow bonding potential. It is commonly written as $\ce{O=C=C=C=O}$. There are a couple of resonance forms which need to be accounted for. Another interpretation of the bonding patter is as a carbon-zero compound: $\ce{^{\oplus}O#C^\ominus\bond{->}C^0\bond{<-}C^\ominus=O^\oplus}$. This description makes somewhat sense because of 2-electron-donor nature of carbon monoxide. I would not expect this to be similar with the nitrogen derivative. It would, however, be an interesting point of study.

Comment: Could someone confident with nomenclature **name** this compound?  I am tempted to call it "diazocarbene", but [PubChem uses that for something else](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Diazocarbene).  The azo bridge is known to tautomerize to hydrazone if there is a hydrogen at either end, but that supposes it is attached to a carbon with a hydrogen to tautomerize.  My feeling is that naming the functional groups might find some data about this molecule, or give an understanding of its problems.

Comment: @MikeSerfas bis(diazo)methane

Answer (score 3):

This compound CN$_4$ is a subject of theoretical study, with a theoretically stable structure. Literature on the compound is scant, but this has been considered before and calculated with post Hartree-Fock *ab initio* molecular calculations.

Stable is a relative term, and I use it here to just mean "has an energy minimum." I have calculated the geometry and charge balance at the CCSD/aug-cc-pVTZ level of theory for this molecule as a proof of concept. In terms of viability in interstellar space, this calculation should represent that closely. It is possible that the transition-state is low enough in energy that even low-temperature vibrations of the molecule could disassociate it quickly. Regardless, to the mathematician this can reasonably be considered stable.

The N=N bond length I calculated was 1.135Å, and the C=N bond length was 1.231Å in my calculations. The partial charges are depicted here: [image]

Answer (score 3):

Although $\ce{CN4}$, called **bis(diazo)methane**, has not been experimentally observed, it has been investigated theoretically and found to be vibrationally stable.

| Structure | Energy | Source | Remarks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [image: linear bis(diazo)methane CN4] | $\pu{499.79 kJ mol^{-1}}$ | [MolCalc](https://molcalc.org/calculations/5ed2425cd4c6373745dd373960fceed0#/energies) | Non-linear geometry doesn't seem to work |
| [image: bent bis(diazo)methane CN4] | $\approx -\pu{672 kJ mol^{-1}}$ | Reference 1 | Bond orders may be incorrect |
| [image: tetrahedral bis(dinitrogen)metane CN4] | $\pu{647.29 kJ mol^{-1}}$ | [MolCalc](https://molcalc.org/calculations/8877e40b15fc549ccb267cbe7af24095#/energies) | - |

#### Protonated bis(diazo)methane $\ce{HCN4+}$

As investigated by Papakondylis A. and Mavridis A. (2005), the protonated form is also stable.

| Structure | Energy | Source | Remarks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [image: protonated bis(diazo)methane HCN4+] | $\approx\pu{-675 kJ mol^{-1}}$ | Reference 2 | Also isoelectronic to bis(diazo)methane |

#### Isoelectronic Structures

$\ce{CN4}$ belongs to a family of isoelectronic compounds with 34 electrons which have been called pseudohalide ions.$^\text{1}$. I don't fully understand why these were called pseudohalide ions; because halide ions have a complete shell (10, 18, 36, etc.). A few others to mention are:

| Name | Compound | Remarks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Carbon Suboxide | $\ce{O=C=C=C=O}$ | Known, stable, linear |
| Dicynamide | $\ce{[N=C=N=C=N]-}$ | Known, stable, bent |
| Pentazenium | $\ce{[N#N-N=N=N]+}$ | Known, stable, bent |
| - | $\ce{[NNBNN]-}$ | Unknown, stable (predicted), bent |
| - | $\ce{[NNONN]+}$ | Unknown, stable (predicted), bent |
| - | $\ce{[NNONN]+}$ | Unknown, stable (predicted), bent |
| - | $\ce{[N#C-N=N=N]}$ | Unknown, stable (predicted), bent |
| Boron trioxide | $\ce{O=B-O-B=O}$ | Known, stable, bent |

Thus, $\ce{CN4}$ isoelectronic analogs maybe linear, bent, or zig-zag (when the ends are also bent). [MolCalc](https://molcalc.org/calculations/5ed2425cd4c6373745dd373960fceed0#/energies) (MP2) shows a linear geometry with a formation energy of $\pu{499.79 kJ mol^{-1}}$.

#### Further Reading

Perhaps the most extensive study of these structures was carried out by Pyykkö, P and Runeberg, N. (1991)$^\text{1}$ who carried out HF and MP2 calculations with a 6-31G* basis set and found the stable geometries, energies, and vibrational levels of such compounds.

#### References

1. Pyykkö, P and Runeberg, N. (1991). Ab initio studies of bonding trends: Part 9. The dicyanamide-carbon suboxide-dicyanoether-cyanogen azide isoelectronic series A=B=C=D=E. *Journal of Molecular Structure: THEOCHEM*, *234*, 279-290. [10.1016/0166-1280(91)89018-V](https://doi.org/10.1016/0166-1280(91)89018-V).
2. Papakondylis A. and Mavridis A. (2005). *J. Phys. Chem. A*, *109(29)*, 6549-6554.  [10.1021/jp0580975](https://doi.org/10.1021/jp0580975).
3. Dissertation by Susanne Klein. *Quantenchemische Untersuchungen an zweiwertigen E(0)-Verbindungen der 14. Gruppe und deren Analoga der Gruppe 15*. Available as [PDF](https://archiv.ub.uni-marburg.de/diss/z2011/0645/pdf/dsk.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for including the references here

Comment: I think the pseudohalide point seems a bit irrelavent, as plenty of things that are not isoelectronic to this structure or are similar to it at all count as pseudohalogen ions. It's a bit misleading, I almost thought pseudohalides somehow referenced this specific class of compound until I double checked

Comment: @thelocalsage you're most welcome. Yes! The pseudohalide part is a little confusing. However, I was hoping someone would clarify why these compounds have been called pseudohalides.